# <head> function called from <body> is not defined

Tags: jquery, scope

In the `<head>` of a webpage I have the following function within a document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
        function productImageCycle(){
            // Function contents...
        };
    });
</script>
```

The contents of the function invoke the jQuery Cycle plugin on a specified element. I can call this successfully from anywhere else within the same document ready event using `productImageCycle();` for AJAX-ed content.

However - just before the closing `</body>` tag - I invoke the same plugin (in the suggested way) like so, in order for it to apply on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
        // Function... (identical to contents of "productImageCycle")
    });
</script>
```

But this means I'm repeating code.

I tried substituting the latter with a call to the function declared in the `<head>`, but on page load the plugin fails to work and the browser console tells me productImageCycle is not defined.

I could easily call it on page load from within the `<head>` but I'm lead to believe this is a bad idea; is it? If so, is there a way to call it from within `<body>`?

NB: I guess this has something to do with scope - I'm trying to get my head around the concept, but it's not quite working yet.

Comment: It's not a bad idea. The ready-state of the whole document (excluding dynamic loading, like XHR calls) goes into that jQuery-call. There is no need to place that code at a certain location, as long as it's after the jQuery-include tag.

Comment: That's reassuring to know, thanks. Purely for knowledge's sake, how can I call it from the body?

Comment: You should define your function outside (and before) your jQuery ready-state. So; (`include jQuery.js`, `define your functions`, `write out the ready-state function`). After that you can call the functions inside the ready-state. There are "some" cases where special functions (with timers and dynamic loads) will behave a bit different and might not load correctly yet on instant-calls when the document is loaded. The best thing to test your own functions is to add `console.log()` "bookmarks" (optional with timestamps) and see in what order your code executes.

Comment: Aha - that makes total sense, and thanks for the timestamps tip.

Comment: If you keep having issues, then you might want to show the code inside your function(s). They might be the culprit causing the possible delays.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not to declare a top-level function in another function. Why don't you turn the head-code around? This way, you can also leave out the `$(document).ready` for future calls.

Head:

```
function productImageCycle(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
        // Function contents...
    });
}();
```

(Notice the `()` at the end, directly invoking the function).

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned - there are many other lines of code within that `(document).ready`. I imagine they'd be better of kept together. It's an interesting approach though.